# can we store values in constant at the time of program deployment?

Tags: solana-program, anchor-lang

`I'm working on a Solana program and would like to understand if it's possible to set constant values during program deployment, similar to constructor parameters in other smart contract platforms. Additionally, I'm curious to know if there is a way to update or change these constant values after the program is deployed.`

Answer (score 2):

You can use Rust feature flags for this use-case. These can be used as environment variables, which allow you to set deployment environments, config, and more.

For example, you'll set them in your Cargo.toml file like the following:

```
[features]
feature-one = []
feature-two = []
```

and use them in your program like this:

```
#[cfg(feature = "testing")]
pub const SOME_VARIABLE: usize = 100;

#[cfg(not(feature = "testing"))]
pub const ANOTHER_VARIABLE: usize = 50;
```

More comprehensive resources on this:

- https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html
- https://www.soldev.app/course/env-variables (examples were taken from here)